# How to listen to keyboard events in GWT table?

Tags: events, gwt, event-handling, keyevent

In my GWT program I have a table that has a selected row. I'd like to move the row selection with the up- and down-keys on the keyboard. So I have to catch the key events somehow.

The GWT docs handle key events in input fields only. But I don't have an input field!

Is this possible at all? Maybe it is a DOM/Javascript restriction that GWT cannot work around...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works by using `Event.addNativePreviewHandler(NativePreviewHandler handler)`

But there are some things to consider:

- The handler is not restricted to a widget. It is global for your application. If you change widgets you might have to register and unregister the handler manually.
- There are browser differences with keyboard events. Some browsers send keyDown- and keyPress-Events, others just keyDown-Events.

To work around the second issue you can get the name of the browser using this code:

```
private static native String getUserAgent() /*-{
  return navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
}-*/;
```